# Cargo box opening system below

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanical

I am currently trying to make a delivery drone similar to ones Amazon did.

Basically the cargo box which carry the package must open to below in order to drop the package.

What I want to do is exactly what’s happening in the picture below or video below but I don’t quite understand how it worked so if anyone could tell me where I could find information to help me build a similar system I would really appreciate it.

[image]

Or for a more complete view of the system look this video from 1:00 to 1:03

https://youtu.be/gFj5SCdSYQg

Comment: I think it is operated through the L-shaped hydraulic system, with the hydraulic cylinder in the vertical position, the horizontal arm is then linked to the cylinder mechanically.

Comment: MIght be worth looking up sources on the design of "bomb-bay doors"  . Granted, those are somewhat larger, and designed for use at much higher windspeeds, but you may get some ideas for alternative mechanisms.